# Excel: display numbers to the precision entered in the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a given worksheet I might enter 47.35729 in one cell and 0 in another cell. So... I want Excel to display 47.35729 in the first cell and 0 in the second. Not 47, not 0.00000.

If I change the cell types to General it truncates zeroes off the end, so 47.30 becomes 47.3. That’s wrong. If I change the cell types to Text, everything displays correctly but my calculations go wonky.

What I’ve been doing is leaving the cell types as Number and manually using Decrease/Increase Decimal to correct the display. That’s an awfully clunky, slow workaround.

What can I do?

Edit, to clarify: I want Excel to display the digits I enter into the cell - no more, and no less. I’m not worried about the precision displayed in calculation results.

Comment: There is no way for that in Excel. As a workaround you can store your numbers as text and use [`VALUE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2) function whenever you refer to them.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is - I typed `47.35729` in `A1`, and `0` in `B1` and I see those exact numbers displayed.  There's no truncation, even when both are set to `General` format.  If I change to `Number`, and back to `General`, then they display correctly still. How are the numbers being entered? What if you have other numbers, like `1.23`, `12345.6789000001`, `1`?

Comment: So your complaint is *only* that 47.30 gets displayed as 47.3? Please try to explain exactly and completely what you want Excel to do.  It might be possible to get 47.30 to display as 47.30, but what do you want to happen if you add 28 or multiply by 50?  (Hint: If you ask for the sky and the moon, it’ll probably be impossible.  But, if you want the grapes, ask for the grapes, or else you’ll get only the carrots. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: **If number of digits are fixed before and after Decimal** then there are many ways to fix the issue like using Formula or Cell Format, and your value will look like **47.35729**. But the same format will *never work for both 4735729 & 0* !!